# Junção de Árvores - joinTree

Tags: haskell

```
data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
data LTree a = Tip a | Fork (LTree a) (LTree a)
data FTree a b = Leaf b | No a (FTree a b) (FTree a b)
```

Defina ainda a função joinTrees :: BTree a -> LTree b -> Maybe (FTree a b)
que sempre que as árvores sejam compatı́veis as junta numa só.

Eu resolvi desta forma : 
    joinTree :: BTree a -> LTree b -> Maybe (FTree a b)

```
joinTree (Node x Empty Empty) (Fork (Tip a)(Tip b)) = Just (No x (Leaf a)(Leaf b))
joinTree (Node x l1 r1) (Fork l2 r2) | alturaB (Node x l1 r1) == ltHeight (Fork l2 r2) = (No x l r)
                                     | otherwise = Nothing
```

No entanto, não compila. Conseguem encontrar o erro ou sabem de uma possivel resolução: 
`where l = joinTree l1 l2`
`r = joinTree r1 r2`

Answer (score 3):

Há algumas falácias no código, como por exemplo assumir que duas árvores com a mesma altura são compátiveis em:

> `alturaB (Node x l1 r1) == ltHeight (Fork l2 r2)`

Tal afirmação nem sempre é verdade.

Seguidamente, registar como resultado `(No x l r)` Será **inválido**, pois segundo a **assinatura** é esperado um valor ***Just _***.

Para a resolução deste problema é necessário primeiro termos em conta em que casos é que uma junção dos dois tipos de árvores é impóssivel:

- **`joinTrees Empty (Fork _ _)`** : Deverá retornar ***Nothing***, visto que quando a ***BTree*** apresenta o valor ***Empty*** este deve corresponder a um valor literal ***LTree***, ou seja deverá corresponder a um valor ***Tip _***.
- **`joinTrees (Node _ _ _) (Tip _)`** : Deverá retornar ***Nothing***, por uma razão análoga à de acima referida. **São valores não correspondentes.**

Agora que temos os casos em que o programa **têm de** falhar, analisemos o caso de paragem:

- Como em qualquer outra ***Tree*** o caso de paragem deve ser nas extremidades, as extremidades destas nossas árvores correspondentes é a seguinte - **`joinTrees Empty (Tip a)`** - Pois este é o único caso possível para as extremidades, e neste ponto devemos retornar uma ***Just Leaf*** com o correspondente valor da extremidade.

De seguida queremos criar a função em si, para formar esta função será necessário obter valores correspondentes a ***Nothing*** ou extrair valores àtraves de `fromJust`, tal modo que será necessário fazer import da ***library Data.Maybe***, e analisar sucessivamente para casos em que é obtido ***Nothing*** na àrvore seguinte ou valores ***Just***.

Segue uma possível resolução:

```
import Data.Maybe

data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
data LTree a = Tip a | Fork (LTree a) (LTree a)
data FTree a b = Leaf b | No a (FTree a b) (FTree a b)

joinTrees :: BTree a -> LTree b -> Maybe (FTree a b)
joinTrees Empty (Fork _ _)     = Nothing
joinTrees (Node _ _ _) (Tip _) = Nothing
joinTrees Empty (Tip a)        = Just $ Leaf a
joinTrees (Node a l1 r1) (Fork l2 r2) = 
                 if isNothing joinL || isNothing joinR
                  then Nothing
                 else Just $ No a exctL exctR
         where joinL = joinTrees l1 l2
               joinR = joinTrees r1 r2
               exctL = fromJust joinL
               exctR = fromJust joinR
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, bastante exclarecedor :)

Answer (score 1):

Eu lembro me de ter feito essa pergunta numa das minhas fichas aqui está o código:

```
joinTrees :: BTree a -> LTree b -> Maybe (FTree a b)
joinTrees (Empty) (Tip x) = Just (Leaf x)
joinTrees (Node r ae1 ad1) (Fork ae2 ad2) = Just (No r aux1 aux2)
                                            where Just aux1 = joinTrees ae1 ae2
                                                  Just aux2 = joinTrees ad1 ad2 
joinTrees _ _ = Nothing
```